# Is there a better way to handle assigning identities to classes within a hierarchy for runtime use?

Tags: c++, oop, polymorphism, typeid

I'm trying to make a sanely-usable implementation of my events system. In order to identify event types,
I have what I call a "type path,' which identifies the path to an event type through the hierarchy.
This way, I can handle, for example, all InputEvents at one place whether they're key presses, mouse input,
or whatever else. A sticky issue, though, has been giving event types their identities. What I've most
recently done is do this by having each instance retrieve a leaf identity from a static member function
of the Event class, which serves simply as an interface other than performing this function.
However, the simplest way to ensure that each *type* has exactly one identity within this structure
seemed to be to use maps based on type paths (up to but excluding the leaf identity/identifier)
and typeid().hash_code().

Specifically, what I want to have is a system to which events can be added easily without
having to look up a bunch of information or perform a lot of silly boilerplate crap. Considering this
(and possibly things I'm not realizing I should want?),

1. Is this design flawed in any obvious ways?
2. Is there a Better™ way than to use typeid()? I've read a bit about it and it seems to be considered something that, depending on the person whose opinion is being asked, should either never be used or be used *almost* never. As it's possible that I'm just rusty or being stupid, I'd like to know if anyone knows of a solution that is, if nothing else, less uncertain (apparently some implementations of typeid() are pretty bad, though I don't know which or if it's bad enough to seriously matter).

Fairly simple example of what I have now:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <map>

void spew(std::vector<unsigned int> vect) { for (unsigned int i=0;i<vect.size();++i) std::cout << vect.at(i) << ","; std::cout << std::endl; }

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo() {}
    virtual ~Foo() {}
    static unsigned int getSubtype(std::vector<unsigned int> typePath, Foo *evt)
    {
        static std::map<std::vector<unsigned int>, std::map<std::size_t, unsigned int> > typeMap;
        std::size_t typehash = typeid(*evt).hash_code();
        if (typeMap.find(typePath) == typeMap.end())
        {
            unsigned int val = typeMap[typePath].size();
            typeMap[typePath][typehash] = val;
            return val;
        }
        else
        {
            if (typeMap[typePath].find(typehash) == typeMap[typePath].end())
            {
                unsigned int val = typeMap[typePath].size();
                typeMap[typePath][typehash] = val;
                return val;
            }
            return typeMap[typePath][typehash];
        }
    }
    virtual void test() { std::cout << "Foo" << std::endl; }
protected:
    std::vector<unsigned int> m_typePath;
};

class Bar : public Foo
{
public:
    Bar()
    {
        m_typePath.push_back(Foo::getSubtype(m_typePath, this));
        test();
    }
    virtual ~Bar() {}
    virtual void test() { std::cout << "Bar: "; spew(m_typePath);}
};

class Baz : public Foo
{
public:
    Baz()
    {
        m_typePath.push_back(Foo::getSubtype(m_typePath, this));
        test();
    }
    virtual ~Baz() {}
    virtual void test() { std::cout << "Baz: "; spew(m_typePath);}
};

class Qux : public Baz
{
public:
    Qux()
    {
        m_typePath.push_back(Foo::getSubtype(m_typePath, this));
        test();
    }
    virtual ~Qux() {}
    virtual void test() { std::cout << "Qux: "; spew(m_typePath);}
};

int main()
{
    Foo foo0;
std::cout << "----" << std::endl;
    Bar bar0;
std::cout << "----" << std::endl;
    Baz baz0;
std::cout << "----" << std::endl;
    Qux qux0;
}
```

Output:

```
----
Bar: 0,
----
Baz: 1,
----
Baz: 1,
Qux: 1,0,
```

This and other tests exhibit the desired behavior, to be clear.
Edit: Previous title didn't really match what I mean to ask.
Possibly relevant notes: This is meant for part of a library, and a highly parallel one at that. I've omitted code relevant to concurrency for simplicity of representing the design, but it may be that such information would be useful for design purposes as well. Also note that I'm still only asking for help with creating/assigning type identifiers; I mention these because some designs may not be applicable given their implied constraints.

Win edit:
Well, I have an implementation that's ridiculously fast and does exactly what I need. With a few derived classes, I can instantiate ten million per ~thread(I added in TBB for some other tests; it may or may not use exactly eight threads however it pleases) spread across the derived classes, each having two or more elements in its path, in typically well under .02s. Original implementation managed about four or five seconds depending on containers and such and was just silly. Result (enough to get the idea, anyway):

```
template<typename T> class EventID
{
public:
    static const std::size_t typeID;
};

template<typename T> const std::size_t EventID<T>::typeID = typeid(T).hash_code();

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo()
    {
        m_typePath.push_back(EventID<Foo>::typeID);
    }
protected:
    neolib::vecarray<std::size_t, 100, neolib::nocheck> m_typePath;
};

class Bar : public Foo
{
public:
    Bar()
    {
        m_typePath.push_back(EventID<Bar>::typeID);
    }
};
```

Comment: Is there a reason you want a runtime solution, as opposed to using type lists or traits to annotate an event's type(s) at compile-time?

Comment: @ildjarn No; actually, I'd love to have an implementation that handles type path creation at compile time. I've been looking into typelists and type traits to see how they'd be applicable, but haven't yet worked that out. The only real goal here is to make adding event types simple (this example only requires that a new type inherit from an old one and have "m_typePath.push_back(Foo::getSubtype(m_typePath, this));" which is annoyingly slow considering that there's likely a good compile-time solution) and fast. I'll continue reading and pondering. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: What happens if you create multiple objects of the same type? Wouldn't your `m_typePath` get bigger and bigger?

Comment: @Xeo ? Each class's constructor is only being called once, and getSubtype() is used only to get the last element of the type path for a given class. If that class has already been instantiated, then getSubtype() just returns the same value upon further calls from instances of the same class. I have tested this and can make as many instances of whichever classes I like and each instance of a class has the same type path.

Comment: Nevermind, I had some strange thoughts here. I somehow thought the `m_typePath` was static. :)

Comment: Heheh, I figured you'd recover from your madness soon :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See final edit to original post for solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would rely on the class hierarchy that the compiler maintains, plus a list of type codes:

```
typedef enum { EVENT, INPUT, MOUSE, MOUSEDOWN, MOUSEUP, MOUSEMOVE, KEYBOARD, KEYDOWN, KEYUP } EventType;

typedef std::vector<EventType> ETVector;

class Event
{
public:
    virtual void appendType(ETVector& v) { v.push_back(EVENT); }
};

class InputEvent : public Event
{
public:
    virtual void appendType(ETVector& v) { v.push_back(INPUT); Event::appendType(v); }
};

class MouseEvent : public InputEvent
{
public:
    virtual void appendType(ETVector& v) { v.push_back(MOUSE); InputEvent::appendType(v); }
};

class MouseDownEvent : public MouseEvent
{
public:
    virtual void appendType(ETVector& v) { v.push_back(MOUSEDOWN); MouseEvent::appendType(v); }
};

class MouseUpEvent : public MouseEvent
{
public:
    virtual void appendType(ETVector& v) { v.push_back(MOUSEUP); MouseEvent::appendType(v); }
};

class MouseMoveEvent : public MouseEvent
// . . .

class KeyboardEvent : public InputEvent
// . . .

class KeyDownEvent : public KeyboardEvent
// . . .

class KeyUpEvent : public KeyboardEvent
// . . .
```

Then to do your test, you would have something like this:

```
KeyUpEvent kue;

EventTypeVector type_path;

kue.appendType(type_path);

for (EventTypeVector::const_iterator i = type_path.begin(); i != type_path.end(); i++)
{
    cout << *i << endl;
}
```

The vector stores your type path. There is no runtime storage cost, and no `static` variables. It might be possible to use `typeid` instead of a manually maintained enum, but with an enum everything is under your control, and you can easily avoid conflicts with other types in your program. Alternatively, it might be possible to imbue a class with the `appendType()` method by means of a template, to reduce the code even further.

It is a little tedious to have to explicitly name the parent class in `appendType()`, but I know of no other way in C++, thanks to multiple inheritance. In Java I could have used `super`, though reflection would probably be a better approach.

Is this simpler than what you have, or am I missing something? Good luck.

Comment: I see at least a couple of problems with this. Firstly, it requires pre-compile-time (developer-time, if you will :) ) knowledge and management of all event types (maybe I should mention that I intend for this to be part of a library). Secondly, that it still requires that each instance of any event type class look up its own type path. My current solution deals with the first bit, but leaves the second and admittedly handles it worse than your solution. I still have faith that the awesome power of C++ can handle this and I'll learn of some hackery that will produce an optimal solution!

Comment: I think development-time management of event types and hierarchy is unavoidable, since it is in development that those are defined in the first place. The trick is to express that information only once. In my solution it is expressed twice: once in specifying the superclasses (`class Foo : public Bar`), and again in `appendType()`. To my knowledge, C++ provides no introspective facilities beyond `sizeof` and `typeid`, so there is no way to determine a class's parent--and if you could, which one would you want? Templates might help avoid duplicating information, with some loss of clarity.